# Android Studio: Using not() does not avoid null unlike when using "!"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am not sure if this is on Android Studio only or in Kotlin language in general but I noticed that when trying to null check a list, `.not()` does not guarantee non null while `!`  does.

[image]

VS
[image]

Comment: It’s the Kotlin compiler, not the IDE. Was that what your question is?

Comment: @Tenfour04 why is it not working and what is the main difference?

Comment: Pretty sure they just didn't implement it. You can submit feature requests on the YouTrack page: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT